# Python list function that takes a list of integers and returns the sum of those items in the list that are not divisible by 3

Tags: python-3.x

My code is

```
def three_sum(numlist):
nums = 0
for nums in numlist:
    if nums%3! = 0:
       nums = nums + nums
return sumz

print(three_sum([1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Above print must show 24

Above code where wrong, guide me,

Comment: You're using the `nums` variable for two different things... Choose different names for different variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also filter your list for all numbers that are not divisible by three and sum it up in a neat one-liner:

```
def three_sum(numlist):
    return sum([i for i in numlist if i%3])


three_sum([1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5])
>>>24
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has few issues :

```
def three_sum(numlist):
    sums = 0
    for nums in numlist:
        if nums%3!= 0:
            sums  += nums
    return sums

print(three_sum([1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]))
```

you were addings nums to nums and in the end returning sumz.

Comment: Thx Mr. Rehan for ur quick responce

Comment: Why tick moved there , although I agree that is more pythonic way of doing the job.